# Calling a character value that has quotes

Tags: r, quotes, double-quotes

I am changing character values into numeric values, but one of the characters is a double quote ("). How do I change this character when I have to use double quotes to call character values?

```
FacebookProfiles.raw$Location <- gsub(""Likes" Section", 7, FacebookProfiles.raw$Location)
```

Here I want to change any "Likes" Section into 7 in the location column. However, when I do this the quotes conflict. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried escaping the `"` with `\"`?

Comment: specifically `gsub("\"Likes\" Section", 7, FacebookProfiles.raw$Location)`

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning and didn't know about that usage. Problem solved